# Selenium Check alert present or not in robotramework

Tags: python, robotframework

How to check an alert box exits in robotframework?

```
Alert accept
Alert dismiss
Alert cancel 
Handle alert
```

In my application sometimes alert will be there sometimes not? How to handle such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use combination of `handle alert` + `run keyword and ignore error`.

```
run keyword and ignore error    handle alert    action=Accept
```

['handle alert' from SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Handle%20Alert)

['run keyword and ignore error' from BuiltIn library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error)

Comment: Excellent Thank you very much, nice and clear with explanation